# Main thread notifying GUI that a variable has been changed C++ clr

Tags: .net, multithreading, user-interface, c++-cli, clr

Currently I am working on a C++/clr application that is slowly making progress.  When I change a shared value in the GUI thread, it's very easy for the main thread to see it has been changed as it would be running through a loop and checking for changes each time (or every few, depending on how quickly it goes through the loop) among other things.

I run into the issue the other way around though.  When my main thread changes a shared (and synchronized) value, how do I notify my GUI that the value has been changed if there is no "message loop" I can see to insert a function into for checking?  I have been looking into events but I'm not very familiar with them and how thread safe they are, but it looks as though using them may be my only option.  How would I go about solving my dilemma?

Thanks.

Comment: Call something like `ProgressBarControl.repaint()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method called **ChangeValue** then refactor all the places where you change that value you're talking about to use **ChangeValue** for the change.

In **ChangeValue**, trigger an event right after the actual changing of the value.

This way you encapsulate the problem, and you can use the event for listening.